# Is it legit having NaN for an empty string in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a csv.gz file from S3 having a string column with empty values. Once I read that file using pandas.read_csv() method ,

```
pandas.read_csv(io.BytesIO(csv_data['Body'].read()), sep='|',compression='gzip',
                                          engine='python', error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True,
                                          encoding='iso-8859-1',
                                          escapechar='\\',
                                          quoting=1)
```

I am getting NaN values in dataframe instead of empty/blank in string column.Couple of questions?

i) Do NaN applies to where type is object?

ii) Do NaN only applied to Numbers (integers, floats) and not to strings

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. Below is the input and actual output I am getting.

Input:

```
    "Obj_ID"|"Value"|"TimeStamp"\n
"ID-1"|"val"| "2020-03-12 00:00:00"
"ID-2"|"v"| "2020-03-12 00:00:00"
"ID-3"|"value-3"| "2020-03-12 00:00:00"
"ID-4"|"value-4"| "2020-03-12 00:00:00"
"ID-5"|""| "2020-03-12 00:00:00"
```

Actual Output:

```
     Obj_ID    Value               TimeStamp
0   ID-1      val   "2020-03-12 00:00:00"
1   ID-2        v   "2020-03-12 00:00:00"
2   ID-3  value-3   "2020-03-12 00:00:00"
3   ID-4  value-4   "2020-03-12 00:00:00"
4   ID-5      NaN   "2020-03-12 00:00:00"
```

Desired output without manipulation of Dataframe should be :

```
     Obj_ID    Value               TimeStamp
0   ID-1      val   "2020-03-12 00:00:00"
1   ID-2        v   "2020-03-12 00:00:00"
2   ID-3  value-3   "2020-03-12 00:00:00"
3   ID-4  value-4   "2020-03-12 00:00:00"
4   ID-5      ''   "2020-03-12 00:00:00"
```

Comment: Can you show an example of your input and the desired and actual output?

Comment: Hey @Gerd I have updated the question with input and outputs .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

From [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) on `read_csv`:

> **na_values** : *scalar, str, list-like, or dict, optional*
>
> Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN. If dict passed, specific per-column NA
>   values. By default the following values are interpreted as NaN: ‘’, [...]

This explains why the empty string is interpreted as `NaN`.

> **keep_default_na** : *bool, default True*
>
> Whether or not to include the default NaN values when parsing the data. 
>   Depending on whether *na_values* is passed in, the behavior is as follows: [...]
>
> If *keep_default_na* is False, and *na_values* are not specified, no strings
>   will be parsed as NaN.

So just adding `keep_default_na=False` as a parameter to `read_csv` should do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the details.